# Display Tooltip if element is visible within the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

after a little advice. I'm working on my portfolio and I'm using a css transition to animate an element with some contact information which becomes active when the user scrolls up.

Within this element there is a figure class element called '.top-bar-avatar' which I have added a tool-tip and bounce animation too. This is all working but what I would like to achieve is for the tool-tip to automatically display and animation to fire when the figure is displayed within the web browser.

HTML 
`<li><figure class="top-bar-avatar"><img src="img/nick_avatar.png" alt="Top Bar Avatar Image Of Nick" title="Find Out More About Me" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"></figure></li>`

JS
`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var newScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (newScrollPosition < lastScrollPosition){
        //upward code here
        $('.top-bar').addClass('top-bar-animate');
    }else{
        //downward - code here
        $('.top-bar').removeClass('top-bar-animate');
    }
    lastScrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
}
```

Tried a few different ways of doing this with yet to succeed. Any advice would be appreciated. Cheers in advance

Comment: Not sure what your desired output is, but I would recommend never hiding your contact info from your page. As cute as the animation might be.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really help. The element is primarily hidden behind the main menu to give the user more screen to view their content. When attempting to scroll back up the user is presented with my mobile and email to the right of the figure. 

What i want is to have the figure bounce animation play and the tool-tip to display automatically with my message. When the user clicks the figure a modal window opens.This should simply be a case of say setting the opacity level to 1 for the tooltip when the element is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved this myself, i simply added and removed the display attribute and modified it's value within my existing code, see below.

Oh I also added a div id called 'profile-pic' to the image element, rather than focus on the figure class it's contained within.

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var newScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (newScrollPosition < lastScrollPosition){
        //upward code here
        $('.top-bar').addClass('top-bar-animate');
        // display tool-tip when top-bar animates in
        $('#profile-pic').tooltip('show');
    }else{
        //downward - code here
        $('.top-bar').removeClass('top-bar-animate');
        // hide tool-tip when top-bar animates out
        $('#profile-pic').tooltip('hide');
    }
    lastScrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
}
```